# Ubuntu 20.04 crashing constantly

Tags: nvidia, 20.04, bug-reporting, amd-ryzen

So i recently changed from windows 10 to Ubuntu 20 since i really liked the distro, but ever since i changed it comes a point where i regret it so hard. My browsers keeps crashing constantly when trying to reproduce a video or audio file, i get this sensation that it's really buggy and glitchy. If i try to open a audio file from my files sometimes it works fine but other times it just freeze and crashes, same thing happens with my browser when it comes to video streaming (Youtube, netflix, coursera). There are times i turn my laptop on (ASUS TUF DTFX 505 AMD RYZEN 5 NVIDIA GTX 1650) and it works perfectly, and other times it has this weird blinking on my laptop screen (not on my extra monitor thou) and constant bugs when trying to open audio and videos.
Something I also notices is that sometimes when i shut it down it takes 5 secs to shutdown, but other times it keeps showing white logs in my black screen like if it was trying to accomplish something. Any advice?

EDIT: this is the message i receive when trying to reproduce a mp3 file:

And if i browse to install this needed layer it says it's already installed
[image]
Pd. Almost all of my apps crash when opening, and sometimes randomly they work.

Comment: Have you tried Ubuntu 18.04? Did you test Ubuntu 20.04 on your computer with a Live USB before installing it? How did you install Ubuntu: did you create a separate partition for your home directory? If so, you can try Ubuntu 18.04 without losing your files, just do a custom install using the existing home partition. Shutdown times can vary. It might not be a problem. What do you mean when you say "reproduce a  video or audio file"??

Comment: Are you running out of RAM? Do you have a Swap file? In a terminal,  `free` shows. Read `man mkswap swapon`.

Comment: @summertime i installed it via ISO with a fresh new USB, i didn't create a particular partition, just opted for the wipe my disk and install setting (don't remember the actual setting name). By reproducing videos i mean mostly youtube, netflix, and other video streaming tpye. And by audio i mean some .mp3 files i have on my local files for practicing german, for some reason sometimes they open and reproduce like normal, and other times they glitch and lag all my cpu (it literally feels slower and laggy).

Comment: @waltinator Can you be more specific please? I'm kinda new on linux and if i run that command it shows a kind of API for memory

Comment: Hi Guillermo, how many files do you have installed on the computer. Do you have backups of your files? If you have two USB memory sticks, you might be able to start your computer with a Live USB and then save your files on the other USB. Then you can try Ubuntu 18 if you don't experience problems with it.